# How does Twitter updates likes in realtime?

Tags: spring, rest, server-sent-events

How does twitter likes and comments are updated in real time on the fly without updating the page? I'm building a twitter clone. How can I implement this functionality of getting event triggered from server to mobile app to update likes in real time ? I'm using Spring REST API.

Comment: [socketio](https://socket.io/) or [Pusher](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-twitters-real-time-likes-feature-with-node-js-and-pusher-fd8f97bee7cb)

Comment: Oh thank you. will check them out @YuTing

Comment: You can look into Server-Sent-Events. It is very east to implement.